# How to join three tables in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, outer-join

How to join three tables in SQLite?  I have three tables, one is `Info`, second is `workForce` and third is `workDetails`.

Table Info:`id(PK),name,status,date,weather`

Table WorkForce: `id1(PK), subContractors,noOfPeople,noOfHours`

Table WorkDetails:`id2(PK),project,workDescription,TableInfo_id(FK) //contains multiple row`

**Table Info**

```
  ID          NAME        Weather        Date     Status
 ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
    1           Paul        Sunny         15/10      MC
    2           Allen       Rainy         15/10      Working
```

**Table WorkForce**

```
ID1          SubContractors   NoOfPeople      NoOfHours
----------  --------------   ----------       ----------
1           AAA                2                 2
2           BBB                3                 1
```

**Table WorkDetails**

```
ID2         Project       WorkDescription        TableInfo_id
----------  ----------     --------------          ----------
1              A               B                       1
2                                                      1
3                                                      1
4                                                      1
5               C               D                      2
6                                                      2
7                                                      2
8                                                      2
```

Assume the **name** is Paul, so all the row with ID 1 and TableInfo_id 1 will be retrieved.

Here is what I tried so far

```
public Cursor readEntry(String name) {

        String selectQuery = ("SELECT Weather,Date,Status,SubContractors,NumberOfPeople,NumberOfHours,TimeIn,TimeOut FROM "+TABLE_INFO+TABLE_WORKFORCE+TABLE_WORKDETAILS+ "WHERE Name= ? AND"+ID=ID1+ "AND"+ID=TableInfo_id);
        Cursor c = database.query(TABLE_INFO,TABLE_WORKFORCE,TABLE_WORKDETAILS,new String[]{id,name,weather,date,status,iD1,subcontractors,numberOfPerson,numberOfHours,id2project,workDescription,TableInfo_id},MyDatabaseHelper.Name+"=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(name)}, null, null, null, null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;

    }
```

My code seems like not working..how can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There seems to be many issues with your sqlite query. Should try logging your query and check for errors.

Comment: I have no idea on joining these table.. It seems complicated..

Comment: Chk this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm

Comment: @CL What? The question is  totally different please...I'm asking how to join multiple table in SQLite, not for nullPointerException!

Comment: Your query results in an exception, which you have kept secret.

Comment: @CL. I get error in my result , not getting an exception, and my app did not crashed

Comment: Then you have not shown the code that you're actually using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist thing you need to do is to add foreign key of **Table Info** into **Table WorkForce** and foreign key of **Table WorkForce** into **Table WorkDetails**

Then write modify your query like this

```
Select * from Table Info tf
LEFT JOIN Table WorkForce twf ON twf.tf_id = tf.id
LEFT JOIN Table WorkDetails twd ON twd.tw_id = twf.id
```

Modify your query based on requirement after joining the three tables.

Check out the tutorials for adding a foreign key.

Comment: then should I add a foreign key of Table Info into Table WorkDetails like what I did ?

Comment: Between,   
the ID in table WorkForce will always same with ID in table Info...Do I still need to add a foreign key of Table Info into Table workForce?

Comment: see, you have three tables right,which have some kind relation between them. Now, you want to query to get the related or the common result from all three tables? How would you do that? there need to be some common name or id, using which you can join the tables and write the required query to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a foreign key to the workforce table the point to ID within the info table
2. select * from Info inner join Workforce inner join Workdetails ON Info.ID = Wordforce.SOME_FOREIGN_KEY AND Info.ID = Workdetails.TableInfo_id Where NAME = 'Paul'

Think that should work have not tried it tho